# Hide supersized_nav if there's only one image in the slideshow

Tags: jquery, supersized

So I'm using the Supersized plugin and I'd like to hide this #supersized_nav below when there's only one image in the slideshow. I tried hiding #supersized_nav if .totalslides = '1' but the actual totalslides doesn't get called in the HTML...

```
<div id="supersized_nav">
View images
    <div id="slidecounter">
        <a id="prevslide" class="load-item">&lt;</a>
        <span class="slidenumber"></span> of <span class="totalslides"></span>
        <a id="nextslide" class="load-item">&gt;</a>
    </div> 
</div><!-- end supersized_nav -->
```

Thanks for ur help guys!

Comment: if .totalslides = '1'   Whats that mean???                        Surely if($(.totalslides).html() == 1), but who knows...

Comment: @roasted   I thought it would work if I could say in the jQuery that if the text in .totalslides div equalled to 1, then it would hide the #supersized_nav.

Unfortunately, while the .totalslides numbers show up when you open the website - they're not actually in the HTML code when you look in the source. Which is why  if($(.totalslides).html() == 1) doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If i get it, you should do something like that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     if($('#supersized img').length < 2) $('#supersized_nav').hide();
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work because the number doesn't register in the HTML. It's not in the source. It literally just shows <span class="totalslides"></span>.. but I can see the number on the website.

Comment: Hard to understand what you mean because unfortunately, i dont know Supersized plugin, maybe my edit is what you are looking for